# How do I link to an item in the public folder from views/controller_name/page1.html.erb in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relative-path

I need to embed a flash movie into one of the pages in my Ruby on Rails app. I've put the Flash movie into the public folder, but I'm not sure how to reference it from my page, which is located at  `views/controller_name/page1.html.erb`. How do I do this?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You can check here for some options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146624/how-to-do-static-content-in-rails

Comment: ben, you should add a little more description here. Is it just one flash file? or is the file associated with a model? If its just one flash file that is in /controller_name/page1 (where page1 one is a static page using a controller) then it shouldn't be any different then embedding the file in a static html file. Also which is it!? linking or embedding? You need to change the title or the description of this question so they are not contradicting each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>[link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to), eg (assuming it's in the public folder):</del>

<del><%= link_to "My Hot Link Test", "/flashmovie.swf" %></del>

<del>The leading "/" isn't strictly necessary, I think.</del>

Sorry, missed the bit where you wanted to embed it, not link to it. Contrary to the title of this question. ;-) This is one easy way:
http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/flashobject

Comment: Sorry i mistaked the vote I'll correct this if you just edit the question

Comment: Sorry about the misleading title! The link looks great, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

we have done this, But we have just use plan html

say your flash banner is at
/public/flash/ folder

this is nothing but plain html

If someone have a better option please let me know too

cheers
sameera