# Routing to static html page in /public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes

How can I route `/foo` to display `/public/foo.html` in Rails?

Comment: Probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146624/how-to-do-static-content-in-rails

Comment: Syed, it's not a dupe of that question since that question is referring to maintaining the layout, etc.

Comment: Just as a note, if you're trying to set up a static welcome page or something rails will automatically show `public/index.html` if nothing else is specified.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can do this:

Add this, into your routes.rb file.

```
match '/foo', :to => redirect('/foo.html')
```

**Update**

In Rails 4, it should use "get", not "match":

```
get '/foo', :to => redirect('/foo.html')
```

thanks [Grant Birchmeier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650475/grant-birchmeier)

Comment: If you're redirecting to an asset in public, you probably want `redirect('/foo.html')` (without the /public)

Comment: In Rails 4, it should be `get '/foo', :to => redirect('/foo.html')` ("get" instead of "match").

Comment: Is there a way to do this where it sends the content of the file rather than redirecting?

Comment: @Emily I would recommend you to use a controller to send the content of a file.See this link: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file .  However, something like this should work. match "/foo", :to => proc {|env| [200, {}, [File.open(Rails.root.join('config', 'routes.rb')).read]] }, via: :get

Comment: Deploying to Heroku, this yields a redirect loop. Perplexing it's that complex to get a landing page to work in rails....

Comment: @Arkan +1 for mentioning the name of Grant.

Comment: @Arkan +1 for a method that works well for domain control validation (DCV) on Heroku when applying for new SSL cert

Answer (score 19):

This can be done without triggering a redirect. Follow the steps further down to be able to route static files in `config/routes.rb` as shown in this example:

```
# This route will serve public/index.html at the /login URL 
# path, and have a URL helper named `login_path`:
get "/login", to: static("index.html")

# This route will serve public/register.html at the /register
# URL path, and have URL helper named `new_user_registration_path`:
get "/register", to: static("register.html"), as: :new_user_registration
```

1. Install the rails-static-router gem: https://github.com/mufid/rails-static-router#installation
2. Restart app (first `bin/spring stop` to be sure app is completely reloaded).
3. Start using the `static(path)` method in your `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: Just in case someone trying to use this for Rails 5, the syntax must be changed. Omit the second parameter, so it should be only `ActionDispatch::FileHandler.new(Rails.configuration.paths["public"].first)`

Comment: Link to [ActionDispath::FileHandler](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ffa13e9d4fdd0684844ad72000c6e949d565dd35/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb#L16) and link to the [Redirect<Endpoint](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d2dde6cbfc11bf39be30d22e2ee7c41c119e0d51/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb#L10)

Comment: Don't ask me why, but this blew up for me in production unless I have `require 'action_dispatch/middleware/static'` at the top...

Comment: This works nicely with a React app that will be, optionally, served by Rails server, like Puma. Just add catch all routes for `GET` and `POST` to point to `static("index.html").

Answer (score 1):

E.g in Rails 4 add the following route:

```
get '/example', :to => redirect('example.html')
```

Also you need to enable static files from the 'public' directory in your configuration:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

OR

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Also you might need to provide your public directory as root in NGINX configuration.