# Rails 3.2.3 returning index instead of static page from public

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app deployed to heroku.  I have a form on my index page that I would like to redirect to a static "thanks.html" page on submit.

The problem is that when I request the "thanks.html" the app is returning the index page instead.  Logs show a 200 for the GET request as though "thanks.html" was found and returned.

Currently my "thanks.html" is in the public folder along with "index.html".  I have no routes in place currently expecting that Rails will always return a matching static page from public when available with no additional configuration.

I did try the fix proposed in [Routing to static html page in /public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631145/routing-to-static-html-page-in-public) without success.

match '/foo', :to => redirect('/public/foo.html')

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using some extra config from the following article to add caching of the static pages. It appears that this is what was forcing all requests to my index.html page. I commented out the rack related info in config.ru and everything works fine. devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-on-heroku