# routing to a static .md page in /public (ruby on rails 2.3.5)

Tags: ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-2

this question was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631145/routing-to-static-html-page-in-public), but the answer was for ruby on rails 3.0+

Basically I want to put my wiki pages (ie .md pages) inside my public folder in my 2.3.5 ruby on rails project. and I want users to access the home of the wiki page when they type `mysite.com/wiki` (ie this would map to `/public/wiki/home.md`)..

how do I do this in ruby on rails 2.3.5? (the routing documentation [online](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Routing.html) wasn't very informative)

Also in general if for some reason I'm stuck with an RoR 2.3.5 project.. where do I go for documentation? It seems the official documentation only pertains to the latest RoR version (ie 3+)

Comment: The guides for rails 2.3.x are here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/ If you're on 2.3.5, you definitely need to upgrade, there are some big security concerns in versions less than 2.3.11.

Comment: @theTRON uha.. tell that to the [fedena](http://www.projectfedena.org/) folks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you want the Markdown to be rendered. If you simply serve it up from your `public` directory, then Rails won't render it.

What you could do is an a new controller, say `WikiController`, which could render markdown files that you store somewhere like `lib/wiki`. I haven't tested any of this directly, so you should take it only as a guide, but it should work okay.

The controller might look like something like this:

```
# app/controllers/wiki_controller.rb
class WikiController < ApplicationController
  def show
    page = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'wiki', "#{params[:page_id]}.md"), 'r') { |f| f.read }
    markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, :autolink => true)
    render :html => markdown.render(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'wiki', "#{params[:page_id]}.md"))
  end
end
```

And you could add a route like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
map.connect 'wiki', :controller => 'wiki', :action => 'show', :page_id => 'home'
map.connect 'wiki/*page_id', :controller => 'wiki', :action => 'show', :as => :wiki
```

The first route handles your special case (`home.md`) and the second will allow you to structure your wiki however you like (including placing files in subdirectories, etc). Linking to `/wiki/help/getting_started` will try to render the file `lib/wiki/help/getting_started.md`.

You also have a link helper method, so that if you need to link to a wiki page from within your app you can call `wiki_path(:page_id => 'help/getting_started')`.

This solution assumes you're using [RedCarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) for Markdown rendering, however you could switch up any renderer you like.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect some issues i got with your approach