# Routing to static html page in /public on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am making one static website a day for 30 days, and I want to create a small Rails app to showcase these websites. I will be hosting this on Heroku. When I run my Rails app locally it works, but it won't work on Heroku.

I read the thread about [rendering static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631145/routing-to-static-html-page-in-public) HTML pages and got it to work! By simply making links directly to my public folder:

**views/landings/index.html.erb**

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <a href="../oneWebsiteADay/colorNotes/index.html">Color Notes</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="../oneWebsiteADay/yeOldeMuffinShoppe/index.html">Ye Olde Muffin Shoppe</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This works, and I am able to click the links and view the static websites in their entirety. When I deploy to Heroku though I receive the following error:

[image: Rails error]

I have read [all documentation Heroku provides](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31#serve_static_assets) about rendering static content with Rails and modified my configurations accordingly:

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :info
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

But I am still receiving the error. Not sure what else to do at this point How do I display static HTML pages on heroku?

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/", to: 'landings#index'
end
```

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Comment: I posted my routes file for your viewership

Answer (score 0):

There is no route in the routes file for your links, hence the error.  In [the link you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631145/routing-to-static-html-page-in-public) it is telling you to define the route in your routes file using:

```
get '/foo', :to => redirect('/foo.html')
```

So if you define your route in the routes file to be:

```
get '/colorNotes', :to => redirect('/oneWebsiteADay/colorNotes/index.html')
get '/yeOldeMuffinShoppe', :to => redirect('/oneWebsiteADay/yeOldeMuffinShoppe/index.html')
```

And change the link tags accordingly:

```
<a href="/colorNotes">Color Notes</a>
<a href="/yeOldeMuffinShoppe">Ye Olde Muffin Shoppe</a>
```

I think this will work, but I couldn't figure out why it doesn't search the public folder on heroku.

Also, just fyi, I think all you need is:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Not all those other settings, for being able to reach the public directory anyway.