# Do even simple pages need routes in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I wanted to make a simple page for a footer of a site discussing the team of the project. Such a page usually just has information and nothing too fancy.

I didn't make a route for it, and just basically saved it as team.html.rb in the folder: /app/views/team.html.rb

I am not sure whether that is the right place for such a file to be saved to.  Where is the best place for such a one-off file?

Also, do I still need to make a route and a controller for this, or can I just skip those for such a simple page?

Thanks!!

Comment: have you tried loading that page, as in localhost:3000/team.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a controller to deliver static pages.

Here's a link to a similar question:

[How to do static content in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146624/how-to-do-static-content-in-rails)

What you can do also is put a static html file into the 'public' folder and refer to it like this:

http://localhost:3000/name-of-static-file

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that will work because Rails expects all requests to go through a controller.  The simplest thing would be to do something like this at the *end* of your `routes.rb`:

```
match "/:action" => "pages"
```

Then in `app/views/pages` you can put your `team.html.erb`.  You also will probably need at least a blank controller in `app/views/pages_controller.rb`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
end
```

The nice thing about this is if you happen to need some dynamic content for one of the "static" pages you can just define a controller method to load it.

If this seems like overkill for your site, you might want a lighter framework like `Sinatra`

Comment: Probably what would work best for me is to define a StaticPageController and be able to correctly redirect the diff static page requests that come in.  How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

routes point to controller actions, not views.

a request to /team would (iirc) point to application#team. If that action doesn't exist, you will get an error.  If you DO have that action defined (with a call to `render`, it will look in /app/views/application for a file called team.html[.erb|.json|.etc]

As the related thread points out, thoughtbot's high_voltage gem is great for a base of serving static pages.